# How to access another app's config file?

Tags: .net, configuration-files, configurationmanager

Is it possible (easily) to have the `ConfigurationManager` read settings from another app's config file?

I have two apps sharing a folder (because they share a large number of dlls). I want to manage only one config file and have the other app read the first app's config file instead of needing its own.

Preferably I would like to avoid writing my own `ConfigurationManager` class to do this.

The `file=` and `configSection=` attributes don't solve my problem.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx) method:

```
 System.Configuration.Configuration config =
    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("pathToYourOtherExe");
```